# JQUERY insert string in relative pretty url

Tags: jquery, pretty-urls

I like to insert a string with Jquery only in case of "some" relative pretty url.

the string that must be inserted contains a value of '/1' or '/2' or '/3'

So a url like:

```
<a href="/whatever"> becomes 
<a href="/1/whatever"> or <a href="/2/whatever"> etc.
```

But a url like

```
<a href="/1/whatever"> or 
<a href="/2/whatever"> must keep unchanged
```

All examples below must keep unchanged.

```
/whatever/whatever
/whatever/whatever/whatever

<img src="/img.png">
<img src="/whatever/img.png">
<img src="/whatever/whatever/img.png">
<img src="http://whatever.com/img.png">
<img src="http://whatever.com/whatever/img.png">

<a href="http://whatever.com></a>
<a href="http://whatever.com/whatever.whatever></a>
<a href="http://whatever.com/whatever/whatever.whatever></a>
```

Comment: A little more information might help. Is it only links that you want to rewrite? You list some image paths you don't want rewritten, but are there cases where an image path will need to be rewritten?

Comment: pardon me: no image paths at all has to be rewritten they were only there just to be sure that the solution with regex has no influence on other urls except relative pretty url's with a document in the root like /whatever 
btw: the variable that has to be inserted is based on a cookie variable

Comment: Do you want this to happen on page load or on some event?

Comment: how to determine which of these /1, /2 , /3 need to be added to the  href.

Comment: This has to happen after page has loaded. All pretty url's like /whatever has to be rewritten to /variable/whatever, so no event (except page load;o)

Comment: Robin, this /1 /2 or /3 values of the variable is in a cookie that I read out with var level = $.cookie("userchoice"), so based on the level what user has chosen the \1 \2 or \3 has to be inserted in the pretty url

Comment: Dude will you check my answer please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try the following code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $ ("a").each(function(){
         var url = $(this).attr("href"),
         count = (url.match(/\//g) || []).length;
         if(count == 1)
         {
             var cookieValue; //set your cookie value in this variable
             $(this).attr("href","/"+cookieValue + $(this).attr("href"));
         }
      });

      $ ("img").each(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr("src"),
            count = (url.match(/\//g) || []).length;
        if(count == 1)
        {
            var cookieValue; //set your cookie value in this variable
            $(this).attr("src","/" + cookieValue + $(this).attr("src"));
        }
    });
  });
```

Comment: how you get /1 or /2 or /3 value in cookieValue is your headache but i feel the code works!

Comment: actually the cookie contains 1, 2 or 3 I add the '/' in the code

Comment: hi @luvTweb please check my answer and tell what problem you are facing. You first selected my answer as correct then you unselected my answer. atleast give some reason.

Comment: Robin, I'm not aware that I checked your answer as correct (because I still trying to implement it / check it), this "select answer as correct" is done by clicking on the uparrow (this answer is correct) isn't? (that I have'nt touch really)

Comment: Ronin, thanks a ton! You made my day(s). I was searching for days for it. BTW: I only used the first part of the ("a") because the ("img") urls should be untouched...

Comment: I not only like to copy+paste the code but to learn of it. I think that I understand most of the code. the each is a loop that scans the page a number of times till it reached the last "a". The count checks if there is a occurrence of a url with a / in it but not // (don't understand the g and the || [] part). Please help me to better understand/learn the code.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really the best solution as it has to scan every element in the page...However just replace the `*` in `$("*")` to choose which elements to target (e.g. `a, img`).

```
$("*").each(function() { // selects every element
  var el = this;
  $.each(this.attributes, function() { // scans every attribute of the current element
    if(this.specified) { // if this attribute has a proper value
      if(this.value.match(/\//g).length == 1 && this.value.indexOf("/") == 0) {
          // if the count of / chars is 1 and its index is 0 (first char)
          var repl = "/1"; // get your value from the cookie here
          this.value = repl + this.value;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Replaces only values which start with `/` and have only one `/` (the first one).

Comment: I'm pretty new to Jquery, so pardon me my question, do I understand that I have to give all the url's that has to be rewritten a class like <a class='myClass' href='/whatever'> ? Is this the idea behind it: by adding a class you have no problems which url will or won't be rewritten?

Comment: @luvTweb Not sure I understood what you want. Do you want to rewrite every URL in the page with `/whatever` as `href` attribute or just some you already selected? If you need to rewrite every URL, just do this: `var element = $("a");`

Comment: what I like to achieve is that every pretty url in the root like /whatever /somethingelse /thistoo has to be rewritten based on the existing of a variable (and this can have the value /1 /2 or /3 and is in fact the value of a cookie) so in the end (in case of cookie is /3) the urls will become (after loading page) /3/whatever /3/somethingelse and /3/thistoo BUT this url must be unchanged /1/something or /2/nothinghappenshere /3/nochangeheretoo

Comment: So basically elements with `/` as the first char of its `href` attribute and then a random string without any other slashes. Do you want to target only `a` elements or every element in the page?

Comment: indeed! only a elements on the page starting with / but without any more / in the url has to be rewritten, full urls like http:// has to be unchanged

Comment: luvTweb what is the problem with my solution?

Comment: @Chris, thanks for all your effort, Robin had the code first that did the job.

Comment: @luvTweb no problem ;) btw I'm not sure, but the code @Robin wrote might replace values like `href="what/ever"` (it's not checking where the slash is)

Comment: @Chris, thanks, I did used your code and it works, although trivial the link is now converted from /whatever to http://domain.com/2/whatever (with http:// in front of it but that is removed in this comment) but I was wondering if it could be possible to have it short as /2/whatever. Is that possible?

Comment: That's strange, there's no code to add the domain name. Which browser are you using? Maybe it's adding the domain automatically.

Comment: @Chris, pardon me, I did a copy of the link with right mouse click in the browser, and then in all browsers you get the full url (or is shown while hovering above the link). But with the console of any browser when looking to the source I see that it is still a short notation like /2/page1 thanks. Your code works great. I'm so happy!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work,

```
$('a[href]').each(function (index, element) {
  var href = $(element).attr('href') || '';
  if (href.match(/^\//) && !href.match(/^\/\d+\//)) {
    // do whatever you do to decide what number to
    // prepend with. I'm just going to use 1 all the time
    $(element).attr('href', '/1' + href);
  }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/6toah7vr/)

This assumes that all of your relative links start with `/`, you would need to change the regular expressions a bit if this is not the case.

`href.match(/^\//)` makes sure the href starts with a `/`
`!href.match(/^\/\d+\//)` makes sure what comes after the `/` is not a completely numeric value followed by a `/`.

I used the selector `a[href]` so it only grabs links with a `href` attribute. It is not as common today, but it is possible to have an `a` tag with a `name` and no `href`.

That said, you might not want to use this kind of client-side rewriting. If your users are running NoScript or other similar security products, it may cause a false positive for a XSS attack. If possible it should probably be done server side.

Comment: UC: thanks for your answer and tips, did start setting cookie (based on user choice with radio button in page) with php but went in some problems. Thought about no-script/google bot: in case no cookie is set then I redirect them to /1 directory (hidden for users by using .htacces) and googlebot can find all other pages because on all pages I have a hard link to the alternative pages in /2 and /3 directories. I use this three levels to coop with three levels of visitors novice/interested/expert and have for all pages three versions available.